# Python: search text file

Tags: python

I have a text file in the following format:

```
XXXX Testing123
    YYYY hellow
    ZZZZ worldd
AAAA Testing456
    BBBB heyyy
    YYYY YoYo
AAAA Testing789
    CCCC hezzz
    YYYY hellow
```

Here is my text searching code:

```
for line in open('test.txt')
     a = "XXXX"
     b = "\t" + "YYYY"
     if a in line:
        print line
     if b in line:
        print line
```

The above prints out:

```
XXXX Testing123
   YYYY YoYo
```

But what I want is:

```
XXXX Testing123
  YYYY hellow
```

Any idea how I can search in Python for this?

Basically I need to first search for XXXX and the subsequent field YYYY should be under this part. If YYYY is not found under XXXX then return not found instead of continuing looking.

Comment: Are you sure that the second line in your file starts with a tab and not a series of spaces?

Comment: @chrisaycock Yes it is tab, confirmed.

Comment: Can you just search for YYYY without the tab? Your current code should have gotten both YYYY YoYo and YYYY hellow, I imagine that's what you want.

Comment: @GUY3000 Yes  but without tab then won't i get the first occurrence only? It is linked, meaning I need to find XXXX and subsequently YYYY.

Comment: It should work.  Are you sure you don't have an editor that replaces the tabs with spaces or uses a weird encoding when writing either the test file or your python file?   (Searching for YYYY gives me both YYYY lines).  Try looking at ord(line[0]) to see what ascii value you're getting at the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this file:

```
XXXX Testing123
    YYYY hellow
    ZZZZ worldd
AAAA Testing456
    BBBB heyyy
    YYYY YoYo
```

You can use a regex on a mmap file:

```
import re
import mmap

with open(fn, 'r+') as f:
    mm=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for m in re.finditer(r'^(XXXX.*?^\s+YYYY.*?)$', mm, flags=re.M | re.S):
        print m.group(1)
```

---

If you only want the `YYYY` group, split the regex:

```
with open(fn, 'r+') as f:
    mm=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for m in re.finditer(r'^(XXXX.*?)^(\s+YYYY.*?)$', mm, flags=re.M | re.S):
        print m.group(2)
```

If you want to lose the leading space, use:

```
    for m in re.finditer(r'^(XXXX.*?)^\s+(YYYY.*?)$', mm, flags=re.M | re.S):
```

If it is a file that you are comfortable having fully in memory, you can skip `mmap` and just read the file into memory with `f.read()`

---

With your comment, you can modify the regex to more accurate capture what you are looking for.

Given the file:

```
XXXX Testing123
    YYYY hellow
    ZZZZ worldd
AAAA Testing456
    BBBB heyyy
    YYYY YoYo
XXXX Testing123
    ZZZZ worldd
AAAA Testing456
    BBBB heyyy
    YYYY YoYo
XXXX Testing123 2
    YYYY hellow
    ZZZZ worldd
```

[Demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/pM4iD1/3)

In Python:

```
with open(fn, 'r+') as f:
    mm=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for m in re.finditer(r'^XXXX.*\n^\s+(YYYY.*)', mm, flags=re.M ):
        print m.group(1)
```

Prints:

```
YYYY hellow
YYYY hellow
```

You can also use a two element [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and test each line for the desired condition:

```
from collections import deque
with open(fn) as f:
    d=deque(maxlen=2)
    d.append(next(f))
    for line in f:
        d.append(line)
        if d[0].startswith('XXXX') and 'YYYY' in d[1]:
            print d
```

Prints:

```
deque(['XXXX Testing123\n', '    YYYY hellow\n'], maxlen=2)
deque(['XXXX Testing123 2\n', '    YYYY hellow\n'], maxlen=2)
```

Comment: Yes it gets the full group. Is the m.group(1) an array? Because I need to print out just the YYYY.

Comment: Just change the regex into two groups.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But l have one issue. For e.g. YYYY hellow is not found under the XXXX group it continues to search and gives me the second occurence. Any idea how do I prevent that?

Comment: What is the definitive grammar of the the occurrence of `XXXX` followed by a `YYYY`? Is it only if it is on the following line?

Comment: Means YYYY must be in the same list as XXXX.

Comment: Because XXXX values are unique but YYYY values repeats. That's why i need to get the YYYY value that corresponds to the respective XXXX values.

Comment: Just change the regex to describe that. Try `^XXXX.*\n(^\s+YYYY.*)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pM4iD1/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a flag showing whether you are in 'XXXX' section. If it's in, make flag=1, otherwise make flag=0. Besides, you need diffrentiate two kinds of line.

```
a = "XXXX"
b = "\t" + "YYYY"
flag = 0
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if line[0] == '\t':
        if flag and b in line:
            print line,
    else:        
        if a in line:
            flag = 1
            print line,
        else:
            flag = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If these are lines in your text file, you can match them like this:

```
import re
print (re.findall(r'XXXX T\w+', 'XXXX Testing123 any text here'))
print (re.findall(r'YYYY h\w+', 'YYYY hellow any text here'))
```

The output match:

```
['XXXX Testing123']
['YYYY hellow']
```

Comment: But this is assuming there are no repeated values. For example if, i have another entry: YYYY abcde below, how can I make use that I will only be getting the first occurrence after XXXX?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re    

printY = False
for line in open('test.txt').read().split('\n'):
    if re.match('^XXXX (.*?)$', line):
        print(line)
        printY = True
    elif re.match('^[A-Z]{4} (.*?)$', line):
        printY = False
    elif re.match('^\tYYYY (.*?)$', line):
        if printY:
            print(line)
```

You can read more about regular expressions [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose variables should define outside loop. And if you want to find XXXX and subsequently YYYY, then you should check two line at same time. The code below works for me.

```
a = 'XXXX'
b = '\tYYYY'
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        next_line = next(f)
        if a in line and b in next_line:
            print line
            print next_line
```

Any question welcome

Answer (score 0):

It looks you need to define a query much like XPath. In its simplest form, the query could be a list: `['XXXX','YYYY']` to search for a branch within trees.

Here is the code to implement the query:

```
def search(f, query):
    level = 0
    stack = []

    four_spaces, tab = ' '*4, '\t'
    for line in f:
            # First get the line indent level
            indents = 0
            while True:
                    if line.startswith(four_spaces):
                            indents += 1
                            line = line[4:]
                    elif line.startswith(tab):
                            indents += 1
                            line = line[1:]
                    else:
                            break
            if indents > level:
                    continue
            elif indents < level:
                    level = indents
                    stack = stack[:level]
            if line.startswith(query[level]):
                    stack.append(line)
                    level += 1
                    if level==len(query):
                            printResult(stack)
                            # clear the stack
                            level = 0
                            stack = []
            print level, indents, stack

def printResult(result):
        for i, line in enumerate(result):
                print "\t"*i + line


f = open('test.txt', 'r')
search(f, ['XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ'])
```

When given query `['XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ']` test.txt as

```
XXXX Testing123
    YYYY foo
            MMMM bar
    YYYY hellow
            ZZZZ world
    ZZZZ abdkd
            YYYY dfkjd
    ZZZZ dkfdjk
AAAA Testing456
        BBBB heyyy
        YYYY YoYo
XXXX Testing789
        YYYY foo
                MMMM dk
        YYYY dkf
                ZZZZ dkd
                        KKKK kdf
```

It produces:

```
XXXX Testing123
    YYYY hellow
        ZZZZ world
XXXX Testing789
    YYYY dkf
        ZZZZ dkd
```